# If dropdown-menu hasClass 'show'

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a arrow on a badge when i click on the badge the arrow goes up and down(with dropdown).

But now IF the dropmenu is open and i click on the body(page) i want the arrow to change back.

I tried it with this code below:

But if the dropdown is open and i click outside the dropdown i still get alert(2) i never get alert(1).

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  if ($('.dropdown-menu').hasClass("show")) {
    alert(1);
  } else {
    alert(2);
  }
});

$('.badge').click(function() {
  $(this).children('i').toggleClass('down up');
});
```

```css
.welcomeText {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: .77em .77em;
  font-size: 80%!important;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white!important;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.welcome-user-arrow {
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu-welcome {
  padding: 0!important;
  margin-top: .3rem;
  margin-left: 15.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class='dropdown'><a class='welcome'><a class='badge badge-pill badge-primary welcomeText arrow-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' align='center'>Welcome&nbsp;<i class='welcome-user-arrow down'></i></a></a>
  <li class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-welcome'>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='account.php'><b>Account overview</b></a>
    <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='account.php'>Account</a>
    <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='changepassword.php'>Change password</a>
    <div class='dropdown-divider'></div>
    <a class='dropdown-item' href='order-history.php'>Order history</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and the code that toggles the class.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I made it and its exact how i see it. Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/ckvwj54g/1/

Comment: Why do you have two `$(document).on('click', function() {`?

Comment: When you click outside the menu, Bootstrap removes the `show` class. So it always alerts 2.

Comment: @Barmar I fixed the double document code, thanks for your answer. Oke so how do i fix it. I want the arrow to go back up or down when i click outside the dropdown menu. Is this possible? Please i need this.